# Windows Service Installation Folder .Net

Tags: windows, service

I have a windows service that is hosting a WCF Service Library.
Corresponding to this windows service, I have a setup project.

I want to change the default installation folder of the service.
It's fine that I can change while running through the installation wizard.
But what settings I need to change at the project level?

Please guide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can can set installation folder in your setup folder where you put output from your service. There are predefined variables for system folders like [ProgramFilesFolder] or [WindowsVolume] which you can use to to construct your path.

[image]

Using Visual Studio you cann't use direct path. Instead of writing "c:\temp", you have to use some variables like [WindowsVolume]temp. You can bypass this using Orca which is editor for *.msi files. It is part of Windows SDK.

Locate CustomAction table and change DIRCA_TARGETDIR to whatever you want.

[image]

Hope this helps.